# show and hide div using jquery, same as mashable.com website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

http://mashable.com/

I have this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".show_hide5").mouseover(function(){
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).next().fadeIn("slow").addClass('selected');
        $(".slidingDiv5").not('.selected').fadeOut("slow");
    });

    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).next().fadeIn("slow").addClass('selected');
    $(".slidingDiv5").not('.selected').fadeOut("slow");
});
```

and this script is working well so far, but it's still missing something, for now it's show the div on mouseover on the arrow as you can see on mashable website but the share area don't hide on mouseout only it's hide once you put the mouse on another arrow.

all i need is to hide the share area on mouseout.

thanks in advance.

Comment: **Here's the answer... working perfectly;**


      $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".slidingDiv5").fadeOut("slow");
         $(".show_hide5").mouseover(function(){
         $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
         $(this).next().fadeIn("slow").addClass('selected');
         });
         $(".main_div").mouseleave(function(){
         $(".slidingDiv5").fadeOut("slow");
         });
      });

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want to fade out `.slidingDiv5` on `mouseleave` event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".show_hide5").mouseover(function(){
       $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
       $(this).next().fadeIn("slow").addClass('selected');
       $(".slidingDiv5").not('.selected').fadeOut("slow");
   });
   $(".show_hide5").mouseleave(function(){
       $(".slidingDiv5").fadeOut("slow");
   });
});
```

Comment: No, i need to fadeOUt slidingDiv5 on mouseout,

Comment: thank you, fadeOut is working well, but i still have two problem: 1) all slidingDiv5 divs is appearing already, so i need to hide them. 2) when the mouseleave show_hide5, slidingDiv5 is fadingout and that doesn't allow me to get the share btns

Comment: Here's the answer... working perfectly; 


      $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".slidingDiv5").fadeOut("slow");
         $(".show_hide5").mouseover(function(){
         $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
         $(this).next().fadeIn("slow").addClass('selected');
         });
         $(".main_div").mouseleave(function(){
         $(".slidingDiv5").fadeOut("slow");
         });
      });